# How many dimensions will a derivative of a 3-D tensor by a 4-D tensor have?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, tensors, tensor-rank

As the title above, I find it hard to imagine or illustrate. It is a question from Coursera.

Comment: Are your "dimensions" orders, viz. $\partial A_{abc}/\partial B_{defg}$?

Comment: Thanks, @J.G. It isn't mentioned in the Coursera quiz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$D_{abcdefg}:=\frac{\partial A_{abc}}{\partial B_{defg}}$ is of order $7$.